# Citrus Framework unable to execute statements from SQLResource

Tags: citrus-framework

I hope there is someone with experience in citrus :)
I've written a citrus (1.4 and 2.3) DB test against an Oracle db.
In citrus you can pass your query either as String or by referencing a file resource.

The String option works fine and the validation succeeds:

```
oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource ds = new oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource();
//init ds ...
query(ds).statement("SELECT * FROM TOUR WHERE ID = 12345").validate("STATUS", "1");
```

However the Resource option fails:

```
oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource ds = new oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource();
//init ds ...
query(ds).sqlResource("classpath:testdata/template/dbQuery.sql").validate("STATUS", "1");
```

Debugging the code showed that Citrus expects all statements in the sqlResource file to be separated by ";".Then it will correctly create separate statements and will try to execute them. However executing statements ending in ";" results in "SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA00911: invalid character".

So am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Consider this to be a bug, issue has been opened (https://github.com/christophd/citrus/issues/79)

Issue has been fixed with 2.5.2 release of Citrus